# Check if Process is closed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, on my Windows Forms Project (.NET Framework 4.7.2), i am trying to check if a Process got closed and then change the Text back to `Inject!`.
**What i have tried**:

```cs
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            easyexploits.LaunchExploit();
            Process[] x = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta");
            if(x.Length == 1)
            {
                label2.Text = "Injected";
            } else
            {
                label2.Text = "Inject!";
            }
        }
```

Since this is only going to update when button9 was clicked, this Code does not works.
Does anyone has an Idea what i could do?

Comment: Are you really wanting to just check once if it's closed? Or did you really mean to ask how to change the label text once the process exits? Either way, `LaunchExploit()` makes me not really want to help you.

Comment: `Process.Exited` event?

Comment: Dmitry's suggestion of using the `Process.Exited` event is great for an event driven program with buttons.  An alternative is, once you've found the original process you can instruct a worker thread to wait for it to exit with [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know when that process exits, you can use code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process x = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta").FirstOrDefault();
    if (x != null)
    {
        x.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        x.Exited += X_Exited;
    }
}

private void X_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Roblox was closed.");
}
```

Note that you have to set [EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netcore-3.1) to true for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, have a nice day!